# Use Flexbox to align items on ends

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to align the items on a timeline bar using flexbox. I want to be able to have the first circle start at the beginning of the line and the last circle to be at the end of the line with the center item being centered. Is this possible using flexbox? Right now I am using

```
ul {
   display: flex;
}
li {
   align-items: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do that with Flexbox (Flexbox is life :P).

Just the ul needs css:

```
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}
```

You need to check this amazing post - [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1):

`align-items` applies to the parent element and controls the alignment on the cross-axis of your flexbox. In you case, you need `justify-content: space-between;`, again, applied to the parent element like so:

```
ul {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

You can check out a very detailed Flexbox breakdown [on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox and absolutely positioned elements you can achieve this:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

ul:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #aaa;
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -150%);
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

li.selected:before {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">Create account</li>
  <li>Understand your role</li>
  <li>Share stories</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the property `align-self` on each item to do so, the problem with using it on the parent element, is that the child items will be aligned to what the parent says. So `align-self:flex-start` for the first item, `align-self:center` on the second item and `align-self:flex-end` on the last one (list items that is).

Useful guide about flex: http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/